# How to access iPhone Google Chrome history over 90 days ago?

Tags: iphone, google-chrome

How can we access **all**  browsing history from Chrome on iPhone?

Does Google Chrome on iPhone have a SQLite database I can access?

Answer (score 1):

You can use google chrome sync option to sync your chrome history on other devices. I believe this URL will helps you https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2591582?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for this but I am trying to access beyond the 90 days that is stored in chrome history.

Comment: He's trying to **access** the data... not sync it.